# Learning Core Data. Entities, Adding and Loading

Tags: ios, core-data

So, I'm trying to use Core Data to save instances of a "Screenshot" class, which consist of:

```
NSString *note;
NSData *screenshot;
NSData *thumbnailOfScreenshot;  
NSTimeInterval date;
```

In my Core Data file, i have two entities because i want to fetch the large images only when necessary, and only 1 at a time (it is to be used in a UITableView).

Entity 1 is called Screenshot and consists of the 4 attributes above, whereas the *screenshot is transient. This entity also has a to one relationship with entity 2(an int called index).

Entity 2 only has 1 attribute which is a Binary data field for the Large images. Also a to one relationship with entity 1.

So, my first question: Is this remotely close to being correct? I'm a little unsure if i even need the Transient attribute "screenshot", in entity 1. **And i am also confused if i need to create a new class for entity 2, which seems abit odd, since it will just contain the images.**

For now, I'm only trying to add and load instances to and from the DB. 
Here is how i (think) i add an instance to the DB, but i am not sure it actually puts it in the DB right away?:

```
Screenshot *s = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Screenshot" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

I am in over my head, so any help will be appreciated. I have read several guides, but none was targeting something similar to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transient properties are not saved to Core Data (they are neither retrieved nor saved out from the backing store). They are most often useful for calculating some sort of property based on stored properties (e.g. I use them for queries based on the first letter of a person's last name -- I'm storing the full last name, but the firstLetterOfLastName is a transient property -- but one that I can order results on since Core Data knows about it).

If I'm understanding your model correctly, you likely want no transient properties at all.

I also don't think you need an entirely new model for your "large images". You can instruct Core Data to optimize it's backing store for large binary attributes by turning on "Store in External Record File". You'll find this in the Data Model Inspector pane underneath where Transient and Optional are set. This will keep the actual backing DB snappy, but allow Core Data to retrieve these large binary attributes and you may still work with them seemlessly with a Core Data NSManagedObject instance.

Also, in general, do not relate items by an "index" value of some other stored Core Data object. There's plenty of reasons to do so, but in general, this is  what Core Data relationships are for. If "Movie" has multiple "Screenshots", for e.g, you would have a relationship on a Movie instance called "screenshots" that you simply add each screenshot to (it's effectively an NSMutableSet as far as you care).

Core Data is an object graph, not a relational database. If you add the same object instance to two relationships on different owner-object instances, you aren't duplicating the child-object -- Core Data does all the work to interrelate them for you (assuming your models are setup in a good way).

Answer (score 0):

I'd rethink this. I think a single entity is enough for this. I'd either add a BOOL value named 'large' and do a fetch when "large = NO" to get the small images. Alternatively, if you want more control, add a 'pixels' or 'megapixels' field which describes the size of the image. Then you can fetch where 'pixels > 3000000' for instance.

If you have a special relationship between two images (i.e. one image is a thumbnail of another), I'd just add a relationship to another Screenshot entity.

Alternatively, you could also make one Entity the "Parent Entity" of the other (see the Data Model inspector when you have an entity selected).

You're on the right track. Keep thinking about how you want to use your entities. This should help you describe the relationships better. Quite often I write the code that uses the entities before I define them in a data model. This lets me end up with cleaner interfaces and less overlap between entities.